# What are some possible optimizations for NSDateFormatter's stringFromDate?

Tags: iphone, optimization, ios, profiling, nsdateformatter

I am currently profiling my iPhone application start-up in an attempt to get it to start as quickly as possible. In the first 19 seconds of my application being started I call NSDateFormatter's stringFromDate method 6 times with the following format string: `@"h:mm a zzz"`

The NSDateFormatter instance itself is shared by all calls and I only set the date format once, but those 6 calls to stringFromDate amount to 17.3% of my start-up CPU time.

Note: The dates are dynamic so I can't just save the strings.

Any suggestions as to how I could make this faster?

Comment: It's taking better than 3.2s to run `stringFromDate` six times?  That's over half a second per invocation, which seems unlikely.

Comment: No, it's 600some milliseconds, 17.3% of my *CPU* time, not clock time.