# Optimizing this for loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, optimization, for-loop, nsdateformatter

I'm running time profiler in instruments. I've simplified the code as much as I can to boil everything down to the exact issue. The line of code inside the loop that has checkInString =[_formatter stringFromDate:[checkInArrayCopy objectAtIndex:i]]; is taking over 90% of the processing time. Any ideas on how I can optimize this code?

```
 NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
NSString *checkInString;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++) { 
    for (int i=0; i<checkInArray.count; i++) { //CheckInArray is a NSMutableArray of NSDates, with about 100 objects inside
        checkInString =[_formatter stringFromDate:[checkInArray objectAtIndex:i]]; //**90% of processing time
    }
}
```

Comment: Though you may not be able to optimize the date formatter that much (if any), you might be able to mitigate it somewhat by reducing the number of loops if working with a distinct set of dates within `NSSet` depending on whether not you are working with minutes/seconds/milliseconds.  So, if you are able to crush those dates to half, then its that many less times you have to format.

Comment: I think you might be able to use GCD to create a multithreaded version of the code - the code seems well suited for multithreading. This _might_ increase performance on some platforms.

Comment: Assuming these are sorted, and that you're hitting the same date repeatedly, caching the most recently formatted date might speed things up a lot.

Comment: BTW - you want yyyy, not YYYY for the year.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, your biggest gains will probably be algorithmic improvements. But the simplification here obscures the algorithm — as it is written here, both loops are pointless and the best optimization would be to eliminate them. We might be able to offer better suggestions with a better idea of what the loops are doing. Even pseudo-code would probably work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I think any big improvements are going to be algorithmic changes that are beyond the scope of what we can practically suggest here (e.g. reduce the amount of looping you need to do, or eliminate the need to get all the dates' strings).

There are a couple of micro-optimizations you could do, though I don't expect them to make a drastic difference. Basically, you can reduce your number of message sends by using IMP caching and NSArray's enumeration methods instead of a C for-loop, which should give a small boost.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
__block NSString *checkInString;
id (*stringFromDateIMP)(id, SEL, id) = [_formatter methodForSelector:@selector(stringFromDate:)];
for (int x=0; x<100; x++) { 
    [checkInArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDate *date, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) { //CheckInArray is a NSMutableArray of NSDates, with about 100 objects inside
        checkInString = stringFromDateIMP(_formatter, @selector(stringFromDate:), date);
    }];
}
```

(Written in browser, so *caveat compilor*.)

Answer (score 2):

With the obvious disclaimer that there may be something that I have totally missed, the current code does the same date conversions 100 times.

If that is correct, you should be able to gain a lot by doing the conversions only once. The following code shows the principle, but please notice that it is untested, so use your common sense when reading it:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<checkInArray.count; i++) { //CheckInArray is a NSMutableArray of NSDates, with about 100 objects inside
    NSString *cis =[format stringFromDate:[checkInArray objectAtIndex:i]]
    [dates addObject: cis];
}

NSString *checkInString;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++) { 
    for (int i=0; i<checkInArray.count; i++) { 
        checkInString = [dates objectAtIndex:i]; 
    }
}
```

The code maintains your use of `objectAtIndex:`, you might want to use a `foreach` or block to do the looping, but that is a detail.

Comment: It's too hard to tell because of the apparent omissions from the original code (both loops are actually pointless as written in the OP), but this might be a good suggestion if the contents of the outer loop actually allow for it, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is pretty straightforward.  What you are really seeking is an optimization for the stringFromDate method itself...

Check this out

[What are some possible optimizations for NSDateFormatter's stringFromDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221732/what-are-some-possible-optimizations-for-nsdateformatters-stringfromdate)

I don't think there's anything too much you can do.  the formatting operation will take up some CPU... unless you can devise your own algorithm based on any assumptions you can make about your input values